# Sub-field in firestore with react native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection "Tasks" that include some fields : The user that added the task, the name of the task, the category and I want to add another one with the steps of the task. Do I have an option to add a "Steps" field (and not collection!), and in this field I will have all the steps of the task?

Here the image of my firestore structure : [Firestore structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5ybJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, just use `update`

`collection('Tasks').doc(docId).update({"steps" : "yourSteps"})`

`yourSteps` here can be a string, int, list, a whole new map, anything. Without affecting the other fields in your document like category.

Comment: You mean that if I want to add a list of Steps, YourSteps will be a list? You agree that in the example, YourSteps is a string?

Comment: In my example yes its a string, but you can write it like this to add a map: `({"steps" : {"step1":"firstStepInMap", "step2":"secondStepInMap"}})`  , try it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I have another question, if I want to add stages in a "dynamic" way, i.e. a task can contain 2 or 3 steps (it depends on the steps), do you have a way ?

Comment: You can use dots to access fields, so lets say we already have a field called `steps`, it has step1 and step2, later on you want to add step3 to them, you do the following:

`update({"steps.step3" : "yourDataForStep3"})`

Answer (score 0):

Important note:
`.set()` can *also* merge new data into the existing document if you pass the merge options:

```
.set(data, {merge: true})
```

`.set()` will write to the document if it exists, and will *create a new document* if it does NOT exist - with the mergeOption, it can merge in new fields or update selected ones.

`.update()` is *similar*, **BUT** if the document does *not* exist `.update()` will **FAIL**..

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set